# simple python for loop doesn't update the element

Tags: python, for-loop

My first time trying anything in python and I can't even get the for loop to update the element. Please, what am I not seeing?

I have this data in a text file

> Y|Contents/MacOS/Safari|1500
>    N|Contents/MacOS/firefox|1200
>   Y|Contents/MacOS/Evernote|1100

And I want to change N in the second line to Y. It prints out the form I want inside the loop but not outside? What is this?

```
def setTrackable(self,appName):
        lookfor = 'Contents/MacOS/'+appName
        with open (self.__dataFile,"r") as myfile:
            data = myfile.readlines()

        for line in data:
            temp = line.split("|")
            if (temp[1] == lookfor):
                line = 'Y|'+lookfor+"|"+temp[2]
                print("line: "+line)

        print (data[1])
        with open (self.__dataFile, "w") as myfile:
            myfile.writelines(data)
```

Comment: you're just setting a local variable to the `line` and it's not being reflected in your `data` variable.

Comment: @HampusLarsson That's incorrect.

Comment: @HampusLarsson If that was correct, the code would crash at `for line in data:` rather than behaving in the way that OP describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use enumeration and modify the `data` accordingly:

```
for i, line in enumerate(data):
    temp = line.split("|")
    if (temp[1] == lookfor):
        line = '|'.join(['Y', lookfor, temp[2]]) 
        data[i] = line
        print("line: "+line)
```

Answer (score 2):

You never do anything to update the values in `data`; all you do is define a new variable called `line`, print it, then discard it. You should be appending that new value to a list.

A more Pythonic implementation would be:

```
with open (self.__dataFile,"r") as myfile:
    data = []

    for line in myfile:
        temp = line.split("|")
        if temp[1] == lookfor:
            line = 'Y|'+lookfor+"|"+temp[2]
            print("line: "+line)
        data.append(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code sample to produce your desired results, please disregard my use of `StringIO` since I am reading your file from memory, otherwise you can use the `csv` module to easily parse this data.

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

s = """Y|Contents/MacOS/Safari|1500
N|Contents/MacOS/firefox|1200
Y|Contents/MacOS/Evernote|1100"""

fin = StringIO(s)

def parser(file_obj):
    reader = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter='|')
    data = []
    for line in reader:
        if line[0] == 'N':
            line[0] = 'Y'
        data.append(line)
    return data

p = parser(fin)

print(p)

[['Y', 'Contents/MacOS/Safari', '1500'],
 ['Y', 'Contents/MacOS/firefox', '1200'],
 ['Y', 'Contents/MacOS/Evernote', '1100']]
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter **more** pythonic way using regex:

```
with open(self.__dataFile,"r") as myfile1, open(self.__dataFile, "w") as myfile2:
    for line in myfile1:
        myfile2.write(re.sub(f'^N(|{lookfor}|\d+)', 'Y\\1', line))
```

As discussed in comments and in other answers, `line` is just a local variable whose scope is local and does not change the original `data`.

Note please don't forget to import `re`.